# Crash on Firebase message - service file not found

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, service, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm able to build and run this app but when the Firebase message is received the app crashes with:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.myapp.MyFirebaseMessagingService:
  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
Didn't find class "com.myapp.MyFirebaseMessagingService" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~SctCMq9gW9e2EQFxhI0GiA==/com.myapp-Dt1ZpS77Njywg1USKxic5Q==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/~~SctCMq9gW9e2EQFxhI0GiA==/com.myapp-Dt1ZpS77Njywg1USKxic5Q==/split_config.en.apk", zip file "/data/app/~~SctCMq9gW9e2EQFxhI0GiA==/com.myapp-Dt1ZpS77Njywg1USKxic5Q==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~SctCMq9gW9e2EQFxhI0GiA==/com.myapp-Dt1ZpS77Njywg1USKxic5Q==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system_ext/lib, /product/lib]]
```

In AndroidManifest.xml I have:

```
<service
   android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
   android:exported="false"
   tools:ignore="MissingClass">
   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
   </intent-filter>
</service>
```

`MyFirebaseMessagingService.kt` exists under `src/main/java/com/myapp/` directory.

(And although this java in the path is suspicious it was generated by the Android Studio.)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Silly message.
The cause was - missing package in the service file.